# How to get a specific section from Microsoft Word using C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, com-interop

Need help in figuring out a way to fetch a particular block of content from Microsoft Word document using the section number in C# .NET.

For example if a word document which has sections as follows:

1. Introduction
2. Format
3. Description
   3.1 Details
   3.2 Tables
   3.3 Figures
4. Analysis

Now from section 3.2, I would like to get access to the table in the section.

Hope I was able to state the problem clearly, let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer from MSDN forum:

here is the link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/0d92f8f1-8ebb-4515-941e-a755bad177be

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with .docx files (Word 2007 and up), you can use OpenXML to search.  The information you want can just be retrieved, or you can change/add to it.

http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/QuickSearchTool.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docx files ( Microsoft Word 2007 or late) you can do it with OpenXML.
Office 2007 and later files are in XML format.
OpenXML

**Visit this link**
[Introducing the Office (2007) Open XML File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx)